# When I pass data from useEffect to react-select drop down, the options are showing, but default value is not

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-select

I'm fetching data from an API using useEffect(). On page load, I'd like this data to populate a react-select drop down list and for the initial selected value to be the last dictionary in the list of dictionaries.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';

function BiteroInfoPage() {
  // Initate array of helados dictionaries and their state
  const [dropDownOptions, setDropDownOptions] = useState([]);
  const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState('initial');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/list_initialized")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({
        list_helado
      }) => {
        const dropDownOptions = list_helado.map(x => ({
          label: x.studyName,
          value: x.studyName
        }));
        setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions);
        setDropDownValue(dropDownOptions.at(-1));
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
      //className="multiSelect"
      defaultValue={dropDownValue}
      // name="studies"
      options={dropDownOptions}
      // onChange={handleDropDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BiteroInfoPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of `useState()` is applied only on the 1st render, and since the api call is async, the array is empty, and the last item is `undefined` when you initialize the `dropDownValue` state.

After you the api request ends, prepare the `dropDownOptions` set the state from both the options and the value.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// simulated fetch
const fetch = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => 
    resolve({ list_helado: [{ studyName: 1 }, { studyName: 2 }, { studyName: 3 }, { studyName: 4 }] }),
    1000
  );
});

function BiteroInfoPage() {
  // Initate array of helados dictionaries and their state
  const [dropDownOptions, setDropDownOptions] = useState([]);
  const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState('initial');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/url_of_database")
      // .then((response) => response.json()) // uncomment in your own code
      .then(({
        list_helado
      }) => {
        const dropDownOptions = list_helado.map(x => ({
          label: x.studyName,
          value: x.studyName
        }));
        setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions);
        setDropDownValue(dropDownOptions.at(-1));
      });
  }, []);

  // demo JSX - replace with your own
  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(dropDownValue)}</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <BiteroInfoPage />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Unfortunately it's still not working. I note in your code above that helados is no longer defined, whereas before it was a state that was set to [...data.list_helado]. If I change helados to [...data.list_helado] then the dropDownOptions render, but the DropDownValue still does not. I also tried creating a const startingDropDownValue = [...data.list_helado].map(x => ({ label: x.studyName, value: x.studyName })).at(-1) and then setDropDownValue(startingDropDownValue) but this didn't work either

Comment: I've updated the answer to work with `list_helado`. Console log the `dropDownOptions` inside the `.then` clause, and see if they are populated correctly now.

Comment: And also `console.log(dropDownOptions.at(-1))` inside the `useEffect` as well.

Comment: The dropDownOptions is as expected. dropDownValues is showing as undefined. My code is:   useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/list_initialized")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ list_helado }) => {
        const dropDownOptions = list_helado.map(x => ({ label: x.studyName, value: x.studyName }));
        setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions);
        setDropDownValue(dropDownOptions.at(-1));
        console.log(dropDownOptions); 
      });
      console.log(dropDownOptions.at(-1));
  }, []);

Comment: If `console.log(dropDownOptions); });` have at least 1 item, then `console.log(dropDownOptions.at(-1));` can't be `undefined`.

Comment: If both are logged inside the .then statement then yes it shows {label:"study2", value:"study2"} as expected. If the console.log is done outside of the .then statement, but still inside the useEffect statement, it shows as undefined

Comment: That's fine. So now move the console logs to the body of the component, just before the return. You should see 4 logs, two before setting the state, and two after.

Comment: The log shows all states as undefined initially. Then the log shows the console logs inside useEffect, then finally it shows the updated states as expected: (2) [{…}, {…}]
and {label: 'study2', value: 'study2'}. But the actual dropDownValue still isn't being shown, only the initial '' that we set at the top of the file.

Comment: Maybe need to do AsyncSelect of sorts? https://react-select.com/async

Comment: Async select options are created on the fly from a query, so I don't think you need them. I've updated the example to show what happens during the render.

Comment: Interesting, so when I copy your code I get the correct plain text rendering on screen, but the moment I reintroduce the <Select /> jsx the problem reappears. I've updated the question with the exact code I was running.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could only solve this problem by creating a studyContext up front to set the states that is then subsequently called to populate the select input:

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';

// Create a context for the study campaigns
export const StudyContext = createContext();

const StudyProvider = (props) => {

    const [helados, setHelados] = useState([]);
    const [dropDownOptions, setDropDownOptions] = useState([]);
    const [dropDownValue, setDropDownValue] = useState('initial');

    // Fetch the list of helados initialized from Flask SQLAlchemy database
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/list_initialized")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(({ list_helado }) => {
            setHelados(list_helado);
            const dropDownOptions = list_helado.map(x => ({ label: x.studyName, value: x.studyName }));
            setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions);
            setDropDownValue(dropDownOptions.at(-1));
        });
    }, []);

    const addHelado = (newHelado) => {
        setHelados([...helados, newHelado]);
        const newOption = {label: newHelado.studyName, value: newHelado.studyName };
        setDropDownOptions([...dropDownOptions, newOption]);
        setDropDownValue(newOption);
    };

    // Given a new helado object being selected from drop down, update options 
    const updateSelectedHelado = (selectedHeladoName) => {
        setDropDownValue(selectedHeladoName);
    };

    
    return (
        <StudyContext.Provider value={{helados, dropDownOptions, dropDownValue, addHelado, updateSelectedHelado}}>
            {props.children}
        </StudyContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default StudyProvider;
```

I was then able to consume this context in another page:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';
import { StudyContext } from "../contexts/studyContext";

function BiteroInfoPage() {

  // Fetch list of helados from studyContext
  const {helados, dropDownOptions, dropDownValue, updateSelectedHelado} = useContext(StudyContext);


  function handleDropDown(selectedItem) {
    // Update selected study state:
    updateSelectedHelado(selectedItem);
  }

return (
<Select
    className="singleSelect"
    defaultValue={dropDownValue}
    name="studies"
    options={dropDownOptions}
    onChange={handleDropDown}
/>)
```